# Journey Builder wait by attribute next activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am creating an email reminder journey and trying to leverage the wait by attribute activity to send 3 event reminder emails ( 7, 3 and 1 day prior to day of event )

the data extension contains the field "event_date"

i have set up the journey activities as below:

wait by attribute is shortened => wba

<wba [event_date]- 7 days > ------ <email: ER1>------<wba [event_date]- 3days > ------ <email: ER2>-----<wba [event_date]- 1 days > ------ <email: ER3>

from what I understand if a contact is injected into the journey past the date of the first reminder email , in this scenario after the first waitbyattribute, journeybuilder will proceed to the next activity.(according to sf documentation)

My Question is:

in this scenario, since the next activity is ER1, will journey builder skip ER1 and process the 2nd wba and send ER2 3days before the event? or send ER1 since it is the activity.

how do i go about sending these reminder emails if the way i have it set up is not going to accomplish what im trying achieve here

Answer (score 1):

No activities are skipped, they will all be actioned, you could leverage an exclusion script or raise error function in each email to review if you want to send the email to the subscriber

somelike if if eventdate - now() is < 7 then raiseerror()

YOu could also add a decision split before the the first wait step to skip the email and join later in the path